# Custom condition for GraphQL mutation that returns message to user

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

What would be the best way to create a response for the user when he is trying to add a new item to an order that is not longer in stock?
Here is my simplified setup:

```
type Product {
    id: ID!
    unitsInStock: Int!
}

type OrderItem {
    id: ID!
    units: Int!
    product: Product! @belongsTo
}

type Mutation {
    createOrderItem(input: CreateOrderItemInput! @spread): OrderItem @create
}

input ProductBelongsTo {
    connect: ID
    create: CreateOrderItemInput
}

input CreateOrderItemInput {
    units: Int!
    product: ProductBelongsTo
}
```

Basically, before committing the `createOrderItem` mutation I want to check if the product selected for the order is present in stock, for example, if the user selects too many units of the product he would get a friendly message saying "only 10 items left remaining", or if stock is depleted "this item is no longer in stock, please update stock to continue".

How can I do that?

Comment: search for 'Error Handling' in LH docs !?

Comment: I could do it via an error, but error is usually for things that go wrong and it doesn't fill right.

Comment: Your mutation can return only order or not ... returning an error - based on **API types**. It's up to you how you'll interpret this error message on FE, it can be shown as a nice looking, friendly message ;)

Comment: I understand how to do it with Custom Exception and Custom Mutation. But was wondering if there is a better way or a standard way of doing it. As it feels more like a hack than a proper solution.

Comment: How about using a custom validation rule to make it work? Maybe even combined with a [validator class](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/security/validation.html#validator-classes) to make it bundled nicely. I think that is the closes you are going to get without a custom mutation resolver.

Comment: ... validations returns messages as errors - this is the [graphQL] standard way ;) ... it's an API role to return a valid response ... you can extend return type to contain order and some other fields (like success, message) but client has to handle errors in custom [non-standart] way (check fields for values).

Comment: Is there a way I can  avoid console error, not that anyone will see that, but its really annoying to see something making an error when actually it's not

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to check the count in your front-end section and simply don't allow the user to add more than in stock units, also you need to check in your back-end if the count is eligible, so I recommend using a complex function, sth like this:

```
createOrderItem(input: CreateOrderItemInput! @spread): OrderItem
@field(resolver: "App\\GraphQL\\OrderItemComplex@create")
```

`App\GraphQL\OrderItemComplex` looks like this:

```php
public function create($rootValue, array $args)
{
    // simply check the count before creating any record and
    // throw an error with the appropriate message if sth is wrong
}
```